# How to include Class file multiple times in loop?

Tags: php, class, foreach

I want to include `Class` file multi times, I have tried to include file in foreach loop but it included only once due to `Class` .

Following is my code.

1) Here i am include a file.

```
$ordersinfo = $ordercon->get_orders_by_ids($p_order_id);

foreach ($ordersinfo as $key => $customerInfo) {      
    include("info_customer.php");
}
```

2) Following code in `info_customer.php`

```
class Demo 
{

    function __construct(argument)
    {
        echo "HEllo";
    }
}


$test = new Demo;
```

I have total 3 records in `oderinfo` but file is include only once time due to `Class` declared in `info_customer.php` file.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Including it once suffices to define the class. Why do you want to include it three times? What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 4):

Only include your class file once, and construct an instance of the class in the foreach loop. It would look like this:

```
include("info_customer.php");
$ordersinfo = $ordercon->get_orders_by_ids($p_order_id);

foreach ($ordersinfo as $key => $customerInfo) {      
    $test = new Demo;

    //Do stuff with $test
}
```

`info_customer.php`:

```
class Demo 
{

    function __construct(argument)
    {
        echo "HEllo";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

Please replace the `$array` with `$ordersinfo = $ordercon->get_orders_by_ids($p_order_id);`

**Index.php**

```
include("info_customer.php");

//a test array to simulate the foreach
$array = array('1', '2', '3', '4'); 

foreach ($array as $key => $customerInfo) {      
    $test = new Demo($customerInfo);
}
```

**info_customer.php**

> In the constructor argument, I have corrected `argument` to be `$argument`.

```
class Demo 
{

    function __construct($argument)
    {
        echo "HEllo";
    }
}

$test = new Demo;
```

If you are initializing the object `new Demo($param)` inside the loop (as in the example above), you might need to introduce setters and getters and call the getter method inside the loop rather than the initizing the object in each iteration. A class with loads of functions will be costly to initialize each iteration.

Comment: In the `Demo` class, the instantiation at the end seems to be redundant now (and should not be there anyway - including a class should generally not have a side-effect of running something).

Comment: @halfer : Yes `Demo` instantiation is reduntant. I kept it there as it was because that was in the question. Thanks for getting rid of unneccessary bold :). A question - Don't you think that having `$test = new Demo($customerInfo);` inside a loop (say executes noticable amout of iterations) slow the execution altogether? (Especially when the Demo class has loads of functions)

Comment: In theory yes, in practice no. For a display loop where we're looking at under 100 loops, the difference will be so negligible to be not worth bothering about. There are plenty of better ways to optimise a web app.

Comment: @halfer : Absoultely. A loop under 100 or even 1000 will not have a significant impact on the performance. Cheers.